# How to limit cpu usage of ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, cpu

I'm converting some mkv to mp4 with ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec copy outpup.mp4
```

And it takes all my cpu, and my webserver is not responding during the process.

Is it possible to limit the use of the cpu?

I've tried

```
cpulimit -l 20 ffmpeg [...]
```

But the video is not readable after that..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can kill your web application because of high CPU usage. You can use **nice command** tweaks the priority level of a process so that it runs less frequently. What's more. it is useful to run a CPU intensive task as a background or batch job.

```
nice ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec copy outpup.mp4
```

The cpulimit command tool edges the CPU usage of a process by pausing the process at different intervals to keep it under the defined ceiling. This might be broken your video conversion. You might try to increase -l to 50

```
cpulimit -l 50 ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec copy outpup.mp4
```

But you can't limit FFMpeg to a percentage of CPU use. Instead, you can try to increase -thread usage or to lower the priority on your FFMpeg process using **nice command** so that your web app can be responding.